# Как убрать плавность в CSS?

Tags: css

Хочу сделать чтобы свинка плавно бегала слева направо и наоборот, но при развороте происходит плавная анимация, и свинка стает очень тонкой. В transition написал чтобы только left был плавным. Или может на js есть решение?

```css
.pig {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/VEJ5nms.gif) no-repeat;
    height: 42px;
    width: 59px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
 transition: left 2.4s;
 animation: pig 4.8s infinite;
}
@keyframes pig {
    0% {
      left: 20px;
   transform: scale(1, 1)
    }
 50% {
      left: 300px;
   transform: scale(-1, 1)
    }
 100% {
      left: 20px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="pig"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`transition` вообще не применяется к анимациям. Можно сделать две анимации, либо изменить параметры одной. Мне вариант с двумя нравится больше:

```css
.pig {
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/VEJ5nms.gif) no-repeat;
  height: 42px;
  width: 59px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  animation: pig-left 4.8s infinite, pig-scale 4.8s steps(1) infinite;
}

@keyframes pig-left {
    0% { left:  20px; }
   50% { left: 300px; }
  100% { left:  20px; }
}

@keyframes pig-scale {
    0% { transform: scaleX( 1); }
   50% { transform: scaleX(-1); }
  100% { transform: scaleX( 1); }
}
```

```html
<div class="pig"></div>
```

PS: Если она не должна бегать задом, то надо поменять 1 и -1 местами :)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 2):

Просто дополнить одним кадром в котором разворачиваешь  и всё.

```css
.pig {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/VEJ5nms.gif) no-repeat;
    height: 42px;
    width: 59px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
 transition: left 2.4s;
 animation: pig 4.8s infinite;
}
@keyframes pig {
    0% {
      left: 20px;
   transform: scale(-1, 1)
    }
    49% {
      left: 300px;
   transform: scale(-1, 1)
    }
 50% {
      left: 300px;
   transform: scale(1, 1)
    }
    100% {
      left: 20px;
   transform: scale(1, 1)
    }

}
```

```html
<div class="pig"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но думаю больше подойдет вариант с двумя анимациями, так как там разворот быстрее.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.pig {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/VEJ5nms.gif) no-repeat;
    height: 42px;
    width: 59px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
 transition: left 2.4s;
 animation: pig 4.8s infinite, pig-rotate 4.8s steps(1) infinite;
}
@keyframes pig {
    0% {
      left: 20px;

    }
 50% {
      left: 300px;

    }
 100% {
      left: 20px;
    }
}
@keyframes pig-rotate {
    0% {
   transform: scale(-1, 1)
    }
 50% {
     
   transform: scale(1, 1)
    }
    100% {
    transform: scale(-1, 1)
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="pig"></div>
```